# Site templates is not loaded when I want to add a new site in dotnetnuke

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-9

I have a problem in the new dotnetnuke (DNN) platform 9.0.2. I would like to add a new website / portal. I choose "Manage" -> "Sites" and click to "Add New Site".

The input form is not fully loaded. At the top of the page I see the message "It appears you have a slow connection... We are processing your content". The list with the "Site Templates" is not loaded. Not even after a few minutes.

I and the server actually haven't a slow Internet connection. All other functions in the menu work fine. Server restart did not use anything.

Does anyone know how I can repair DNN or create a new site in a different way?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution myself. The IIS AppPool did not have the correct permissions on the directory. I have now given modify rights to the AppPool user (IIS_IUSRS).

Now loading the templates and adding a new site is working.

The permissions had disappeared after a backup restore...